# Remove "Method is never used" warning for OnClick annotation in Android Studio

Tags: methods, annotations, android-studio, warnings, butterknife

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I am using the Butterknife 5.0 with the latest version of Android Studio(0.5.7). How can I remove the "Method is never used" warning for methods that use the 'OnClick' Annotation of ButterKnife.I noticed that Eclipse doesnt give this warning for the 'OnClick' methods. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816338/3007795 - kind of same

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The correct way in Android Studio to suppress these warnings is to press **Alt+Enter** on the method giving the *Method 'yourFunction()' is never used* warning, and selecting

```
Suppress for methods annotated by 'butterknife.OnClick'
```

Comment: how do you undo this action?

Comment: FYI, it adds exactly what @codesparkle said (tested with AS 2.0)

Answer (score 92):

Simply add this annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

Just like that:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@OnClick(R.id.myButton)
public void clickHandler()
{
    // ...
}
```

My personal preference (which I see as good practice) is to add a comment with a brief explanation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused") // it's actually used, just injected by Butter Knife
```

Comment: it can be more detailed:
@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedParameters"})

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unused") did not work for me, but @Suppress("unused") did.

Answer (score 11):

Osvald's answer is spot on.

However, if you want to avoid suppressing warnings separately for each type of butterknife annotation, *follow his instructions,* and then open up `.idea/misc.xml` and find this section:

```
<component name="EntryPointsManager">
  <entry_points version="2.0" />
  <list size="1">
    <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="butterknife.OnClick" />
  </list>
</component>
```

Therein, simply replace `butterknife.OnClick` with **`butterknife.*`**.

From now on, all your injected event handlers will evade the warning.

Comment: Not bad, but I think one doesn't usually commit `.idea` files into the repository, so every developer has to do this trick individually, whereas an annotation works automatically for everyone since it's an integral part of the codebase

Comment: @KonradMorawski Both methods only change `.idea` files so you'd have the same issue either way.  What is and is not committed to a repository depends entirely on what the repository is configured to ignore.

Comment: @Tom no, SuppressWarnings is an annotation used in code files directly

Comment: Oh I see, I was referring to Osvald's and Codesparkle's answers, which only change .idea/misc.xml file.  You meant annotations.  I'll just shuffle over here...

Answer (score 5):

Add another dependency for the compiler:

*Gradle*

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0' // new line
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0' // original library
}
```

This is recommended on the [official website](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/#download).

Remember to *Build -> Rebuild Project*, so it will generate usages and make the warning go away.

Answer (score 2):

With **Kotlin**, you should use **@Suppress("unused")** instead of @SuppressWarnings("unused")

```
@Suppress("unused") 
fun foo() {

}
```