# butterknife prompt onclick method never unused

Tags: android, prompt, butterknife

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
    void loginClick(){
        //
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

I add butterknife in my project and it works well.But there is a 'problem' makes me confused.[image]

it always prompt Method is never used.actully I know the method used.I just don't wanna see this tip.Is there anyone who can help me to get rid of this tip.

**PS:when I run the butterknife sample, I didn't see any tips like this.**

Comment: Post your code instead of screenshot

Comment: Edit your code first

Comment: thanks, I got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way in Android Studio to suppress these warnings is to press **Alt+Enter** on the method giving the Method '`yourFunction()'` is never used warning, and selecting

```
Suppress for methods annotated by 'butterknife.OnClick'
```

Please go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382532/remove-method-is-never-used-warning-for-onclick-annotation-in-android-studio) for more details and more options.

Answer (score 1):

Place cursor on loginClick method and click alt+enter.

It will give suggestions and click on

`Suppress for methods annotated by 'butterknife.OnClick'`