# How to avoid complier warning Parameter 'x' is never used

Tags: android-studio, android-lint

Suggest the best way to solve this type of compiler warning in Android Studio 3.3

Note: I found many solutions to avoid the warnings and uncheck the Studio inspection. But I am expecting something different.

Example:
If warning **Parameter 'view1' is never used** is in the button onClick method.

*Method*

```
fun buttonClicked(view1: View) {
//   Call Intent to new Activity . 
// Parameter **view1** is not used  }
```

*Call method from XML*

```
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/button_id"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:onClick="@{viewModel::buttonClicked}"
 android:text="@string/example" />.
```

So we need **(view1: View)** parameter for the method for onClick. But it is not used. How can I solve this warning?. (Just one example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382532/remove-method-is-never-used-warning-for-onclick-annotation-in-android-studio

Comment: @Zoe what will be the command in mac machine. Also, I'm not using butterknife in my project

Comment: Same idea, different keys. I have no clue what alt is on a mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a few days to figure out the exact way to manage this warning without using **@SuppressWarnings("unused")**

> **android:onClick="@{viewModel::buttonClicked}"**  is equal to **android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.buttonClicked(v)}**, both were calling same method ***fun buttonClicked(view1: View)*** in Kotlin. (just try to mention difference between '::' and '.' usage)

So I fixed my warning my calling a method explicitly instead of using -'::'

```
fun buttonClicked() // Button onClick function
```

It will be called from XML - >**android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.buttonClicked()}"**. Thus "Parameter view1 is never used" will not occur any more.

Simple Fix !! Happy Coding

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unused") did not work for me, but @Suppress("unused") did.

Answer (score 0):

I just make sure to use the view variable in a cheap way so the error goes away:

```
Log.d("IGNORE", "Logging view to curb warnings: $view1")
```

Not an elegant answer, but one Log isn't gonna slow down the app and it does the trick